# Castle Winsdor automatic resolving generic interfaces work incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I use Castle Winsdor as DI resolving tool.

I map entites code:

```
container.RegisterServices(
    Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(GridEntityService<,>)));
```

I have Interface with two generics:

```
IGridEntityService<TEntity,TService>
```

And I have two implementations of this interface. First:

```
GridEntityService<TEntity,TService>: IGridEntityService<TEntity,TService>
```

And also I have custom implementation. Second:

```
TaskServiceOne : GridEntityService<User, LoginService> { }
TaskServiceTwo : GridEntityService<Report, LoginService> { }
```

In my controller constructor:

```
public UserController(
    IGridEntityService<User, LoginService> userService,
    IGridEntityService<Report, LoginService> reportService)
{
    // Get Correct one TaskServiceOne
    GridEntityService = userService;
    // Get GridEntityService<Report, LoginService> 
    // not the TaskServiceTwo
    GridSecondEntityService = reportService
}
```

How can I say to the Castle Windsor to get correct one? Why did they get incorrect? I have other places, where I have the similar services and they work fine.

Edited.
Anwser to comment. You are right. It`s extension method:

```
 public static void RegisterServices(this IWindsorContainer container, Assembly assembly)
            {
                container.Register(
                    AllTypes.FromAssembly(assembly).Where(t => true).WithService.AllInterfaces().Configure(
                        reg => reg.LifeStyle.Custom<InstantiateAndForgetIt>()));
            }
```

Comment: What windsor version are you using. I don't seem to have a container.RegisterServices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was cashed Services assembly. It was in the bin folder. It takes the old code, where were no implementation of TaskServiceTwo. I cleared solutions and manually deleted the Service.dll. It fixed the issue without changing the code.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, Windsor will pick a more specific type, over the less specific type. That's why, if you have component / service pairs:

```
TaskServiceTwo / IGridEntityService<Report, LoginService>
GridEntityService<, > / IGridEntityService<, >
```

it will by default pick the first component, because it is more specific than the second one.

Now the proper way through this, varies from application to application.

Why do you even have `TaskServiceTwo` exposing `IGridEntityService<Report, LoginService>` if you do not wish it to satisfy this service?

Perhaps its registration should be altered, or it should not be registered at all?

If you do want to keep it (perhaps some other components depend on it) and just override the default for this single particular case... well, you can.

when registering `UserController` you should configure it to depend on `GridEntityService<, >`. [The documentation shows you all the options for doing that](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-Dependencies.ashx#Explicit_service_dependencies%3a_DependencyOnComponent__1).

Comment: Thank you for your time. I want to get TaskServiceTwo. I have founded that the issue was. It wasn`t the Castle Winsdor bug. It was the VS2012 bug which made me crazy. It cashed Services assambly and put it to the Bin folder. So whatever I do it give me old version of code. Today I cleared solutions and manually delete the Service bin and all start working properly. So thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is an easier way, but as far as I know, you have to map the open generic type explicitly, as follows:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.From( 
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes()))
    .BasedOn(typeof(IGridEntityService<,>))
    .Unless(t => t.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
    .WithService.Select((_, baseTypes) =>
    { 
        return 
            from t in baseTypes
            where t.IsGenericType
            let td = t.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
            where td == typeof(IGridEntityService<,>)
            select t;
    })
    .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient));


container.Register(Component
    .For(typeof(IGridEntityService<,>))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(GridEntityService<,>)))
```